# How to obtain the line element in cylindrical coordinates, using definition of differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

In general, a volume element is a k-form on an K-dimensional manifold. a k-form w on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is defined as

$w(x) = \sum_{i_{1}<i_{2}<...<i_{k}} w_{i_{1}i_{2}...i_{k}}(x) \cdot\mathrm{d} x_{i_{1}}\wedge \mathrm{d} x_{i_{2}}\wedge...\wedge \mathrm{d} x_{i_{k}}$

For cylindrical coordinates, the line element is a 1-form in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, and $\mathrm{ds}= \mathrm{dr}\hat{\mathrm{r}} + \mathrm{dz}\hat{\mathrm{z}}+\mathrm{r}\mathrm{d}\phi \hat{\phi}$. I can understand how this follows from the definition given above, since the line element is a 1-form. But I don't understand where the factor r in front of the $\mathrm{d}\phi \hat{\phi}$ comes from, using the definition of the differential form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* In rectangular coordinates, an infinitesimal distance is given by $\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm dx^2+\mathrm dy^2+\mathrm dz^2.$ Then performing the transformation $x=r\cos\phi,\,y=r\sin\phi$ produces $$\mathrm dx=-r\sin\phi\mathrm d\phi+\cos\phi\mathrm dr,\,\mathrm dy=r\cos\phi\mathrm d\phi+\sin\phi\mathrm dr.$$ Substituting this into the first equation gives the desired result.